# Copy cells of specific colour of a worksheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy the white cells of a worksheet to the same places in another workbook?

I have two workbooks with multiple sheets and they are the same, but the source workbook has some white cells filled and the destination workbook has these cells empty. I want to transfer the values from the source white cells to the destination white cells.

Also, I want to fill the empty white cells with "0".

I found code to copy all coloured cells to another worksheet but they do not transfer to another workbook and the exact places.

```vb
Sub CopyHighlightedTransactions()

Dim TransIDField As Range
Dim TransIDCell As Range
Dim ATransWS As Worksheet
Dim HTransWS As Worksheet

Set ATransWS = Worksheets("All Transactions")
Set TransIDField = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set HTransWS = Worksheets("Highlighted Transactions")

For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField

    If TransIDCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        
        TransIDCell.Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:= _
          HTransWS.Range("A1").Offset(HTransWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            
    End If

Next TransIDCell

HTransWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If the animation above is something that you mean (if I understand you correctly), maybe you want to try the sub below :

```
Sub test()
Dim wbS As Worksheet: Dim wbT As Worksheet
Dim rgData As Range: Dim c As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'prepare variable for the workbook and sheet of the source and target
Set wbS = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
Set wbT = Workbooks("Target.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

'the range of the data to be searched
Set rgData = wbS.Range("A1:D10") 'change as needed

'prepare the color to be searched
  With Application.FindFormat
  .Clear
  .Interior.Color = vbWhite
  End With

'start searching as c variable
Set c = rgData.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)

'loop until all cells in rgData is checked if the color is white or not
'if found white then copy the c, paste to wbT with that c address
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Copy Destination:=wbT.Range(c.Address)
                Set c = rgData.Find(What:=vbNullString, after:=c, SearchFormat:=True)
            Loop While c.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
    
End Sub
```

To test the code, make a copy of your workbook (both the source and the target). Copy the sub, paste on the copied workbook then run it. Both workbooks must be opened. It will take time if your data range is big as the code will check all the cell which has white color within the rgData.

> the source workbook has some **white cells filled**

Please remember, the code is looking for the cell which is filled with white color.

---

I'm curious if the test2 sub below is faster because there's no loop.

```
Sub test2()
Dim rgW_orig As Range: Dim rgDest As Range
Dim rgW As Range: Dim rgX As Range
Dim rgBlank As range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rgW_orig = Sheets(1).Range("A1:D10")
Set rgDest = Workbooks("Target.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range(rgW_orig.Address)

With Application.FindFormat.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Workbooks.Add
    Set rgW = ActiveSheet.Range(rgW_orig.Address)
    rgW_orig.Copy Destination:=rgW
        With rgW
            .Replace What:="", Replacement:=True, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
                :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=False
            Set rgX = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
        End With
    rgW.Value = "": rgX.Value = 1
    set rgBlank = rgW.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
    rgW.Value = rgW_orig.Value
    rgBlank.ClearContents
    rgW.Copy
    rgDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        True, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

The test2 macro use a new workbook as a helper, and assumes that the range of data in the Source.xlsm (where the macro reside) is the same within the range of data in the Target.xlsx.

First, it set a range the same address with rgW_orig in the new workbook as rgW variable. Then it copy the rgW_orig and paste it to rgW

Then within the new workbook (the helper workbook) :
it get all cells which filled with white color (by replacing the cell with white color with TRUE boolean), set it as rgX variable.

Next, it fill the whole range (the rgW) with blank, and fill the rgX with 1, then get all cells which has no value (blank) as rgBlank variable.

It copy again the rgW_orig into rgW, then clear the content of rgBlank. Now in this helper workbook within the rgW, the cells with value are only the one with white color, the rest are blank.

Finally it copy the rgW, paste "skip blank" into rgDest then close the helper workbook without saving.

Still not so sure though if this test2 sub is faster than the sub before.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does exactly what I want, but it takes a lot of time as you suggested.

Comment: @Antogram, if you're interested, maybe you want to try the second sub in case it runs faster than the first sub.